# Width 100% overflowing horizontally

Tags: css

I am using the following CSS to get my widths on my header and section.

```
header {
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
    padding:60px;
    float:left;
    background: url('extras/header.jpg') repeat-x;
}

section {
width: 100%;
float: left;
    padding:20px 60px;
height:760px;
    background: url('extras/body.jpg') repeat-x;
}
```

On IE, Chrome and FF, the design is being stretched horizontally and producing an X axis scrollbar. Even of resolutions upwards of 1300px.

Can anyone see why?
Do I need to specify more code?

Thanks

Comment: Because your width will always be 100% + 120px (due to the padding)

Comment: I don't know what your html looks like, but keep in mind that the width attribute applies to its parent div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Padding is always added with your defined width. So actually your container will get 100%+120px width from the css file. So reduce your width to less than 100%.

Comment: But I wouldn't know the exact % to reduce it to? Does margin add onto the width too? Is there a workaround for it? I need it to stretch the entire screen but take into account the padding? Best solution to add another layer in behind?

Comment: the best solution would be to put your header and section in a div wrapper i think

Comment: Yes.. the best solution is, add a wrapper div which have the 100% width and create one more container div inside the wrapper div and add padding on that container div not on the wrapper div.

Comment: Ahhh ok, and then add the header and section inside both the div's? Will the background from the header and section be 100% across the screen still? Thanks.

Comment: try this out <div style="width:100%;height:100px;background-color:#cdcdcd;">
 <div style="padding:60px;width:auto;height:50px;"></div>
</div>

Comment: That didn't work, it's moved the colours centrally. The background colours are based on the header and section so parent divs end up with white (or grey in your case) padding!

Comment: So how I've fixed it is by adding the extra divs ontop of the header and section rather than behind them! Thanks for the help guys, got me thinking straight. Been a good while since I used any CSS.

Comment: It's just an example of HTML code. Structure should be Wrapper Div > header Div + section Div < Wrapper Div close.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two div, and set padding in outer div (please remove padding from header and section also). Like that:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    /* padding:60px; */ /* Move it to outer div */
    float:left;
    background: url('extras/header.jpg') repeat-x;
}

.section {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    /*padding:20px 60px;*/ /* Move it to outer div */
    height:760px;
    background: url('extras/body.jpg') repeat-x;
}

<!-- And in your code: -->
<div style="padding: 60px;">
   <div class="header">
      <p>Content here</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks bud, this is what I went for in the end because you'd answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to concern yourself with the math of calculating the width-padding-margin-doodahs-demwutwuts you can declare your `headers` and `sections`to have the `box-sizing: border-box`, so your final rendered boxes will be of the declared width and the paddings will be cut inside the boxes. [More info](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)